# Canon Printer "Does not accept Jobs" on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, printing, canon, pixma

My printer is Canon Pixma MX922. Its on my home wifi, and other Macbook computers on the network can access it. However, I can't print to it from my new Ubuntu 18.04 computer.

1. The printer is automatically detected by the OS, but it shows "Does not accept jobs" as show below.

[image]

2. I can select it as a target printer in Chrome and print to it, but nothing happens. Not even an error message.
3. I tried removing the printer, but it gets added automatically by the OS.
4. On the CUPS printer list page ( http://localhost:631/printers/ ) the printer is **not** listed. And when I choose the "Find new printers" option under the Administration page, it says that no printers are found. It's odd that the CUPS localhost page doesn't see the printer but the Ubuntu printers settings does.
5. The error log, accessible in the localhost CUPS page, shows this:

   `E [07/Jul/2018:01:37:15 -0700] [CGI] Unable to create PPD file: Printer does not support required IPP attributes or document formats.
   E [07/Jul/2018:01:37:15 -0700] copy_model: empty PPD file
   E [07/Jul/2018:01:37:15 -0700] [Client 261] Returning IPP server-error-internal-error for CUPS-Add-Modify-Printer (ipp://localhost/printers/Canon-MX920-series) from localhost`
6. Driverless results:

   `$ driverless
   ipp://91825D000000.local:631/ipp/print`

Any tips? Or anything else I can try?

Comment: Edit the results of `driverless`  into the question please.

Comment: @Rinzwind done!

Comment: I've had a similar problem with my Brother MFC 2710. It normally prints fine even if it "Does not accept jobs", but when it *doesn't* print, the solution for me is to click "Additional Printer Settings" from the Settings->Devices->Printers page. There, I double-click on the printer icon, go to "Policies" and ensure that "Enabled" is checked, then click Apply or OK. Stalled jobs start right up! This has also worked for me with other printers, with other Ubuntu 18.04 machines.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I was having the same issue after upgrading to 18.04 and was finally able to resolve it.  It seems to be related to an error between adding a printer directly through CUPS vs. using the add printer device option. I also noticed the CUPS errors when attempting to add the printer generically through settings, and after researching CUPS errors here is what I did that resolved the issue:

1) Removed the printer through the interface

2) Shut down the printer completely and re-connected it to the WIFI network.

3) Added the printer back selecting the driverless option through the Add Printer interface

(Note: steps 1-3 may not be completely necessary, but I did them anyway in the interest documenting a path to resolution)

4) From there, I accessed CUPS through: http://localhost:631/admin

(Note: after logging in I noticed the same thing that you did - that the printer wasn't listed at all)

5) From here I proceeded to Add a new printer directly through the CUPS admin page

The printer showed up (Cannon MX922) and I selected to add it using the Default settings.

After that, the printer then showed up through the Device settings (as well as in CUPS), and I also noticed that it not only shows as Ready, but I also have the ink levels showing as well.  I then successfully printed a test page and things appear to be working normally (I tried to upload a screen shot for the link below as verification).

[Screenshot from Printer listings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ye19D.jpg)

From here, I intend to add printers directly through the CUPS admin page vs. the Device settings, as this seems to be the root of the issue.

Hope this helps.

Comment: when I try clicking on Add Printer, I get the following error 'Enter your username and password or the root username and password to access this page. If you are using Kerberos authentication, make sure you have a valid Kerberos ticket.' but with no way of entering those values (and not sure what they would be anyways....)

Comment: I entered my ubuntu username and pwd at this point, and it worked

Answer (score 2):

Driverless comes from Airprint support; that was introduced into Ubuntu 17.04 and this MX922 is listed as supported;

What about installing the drivers that Canon offer? ..to do that go here http://support-asia.canon-asia.com/contents/ASIA/EN/0100517002.html and click to download and **SAVE** what will be cnijfilter-mx920series-3.90-1-deb.tar.gz

Open a terminal; copy each command below 1 by 1; paste into the terminal and hit the ENTER key; move on to the next command

```
cd Downloads

tar -zxvf cnijfilter-mx920series-3.90-1-deb.tar.gz

cd cnijfilter-mx920series-3.90-1-deb

sudo ./install.sh
```

that last command runs the install script; watch as it will ask you questions; it should set up a new icon in your **PRINTERS** folder; if you right-click on it, it should say in the **MAKE & MODEL** line that is uses

> cnijfilter-mx920series-3.90-1

so you can see which is which: if the new one works, and the old doesn't maybe delete the old; but Ubuntu may attempt another driverless install; you might have to live with that

Comment: Hmm... Ubuntu shows it supports the printer, implying that no external driver is needed. And Canon's support page explicitly states that no driver is needed for Ubuntu. I'm wondering why neither Canon nor Ubuntu point me to download this driver. Also, the page says that this was last updated in 2013. I'm hesitant to try it.

Comment: the printer came out in 2013; with its driver; neither has changed since then; it is up to you; gutenprint drivers (open-source) are another set of drivers; turboprint http://www.turboprint.info/ is yet another driver system to drive printers ...........

Answer (score 0):

I've managed my mx492 to work (as of wonder, scanner part of it worked with no issues!) on 18.04 through CUPS by adding it as CUPS+Gutenprint v5.2.13 (color).

Other options didn't work.